# Fill container with DataTable in Shiny tabpanel using Flexdashboard

Tags: r, datatables, shiny, flexdashboard

I am writing a flexdashboard that shows dataframes with DataTable (DT) in tabs.

When using `fillContainer=T` on DT and normal flexdashboard tabs, I get the desired result: my datatables fill their whole container but not more.

[Shinyapps.io : Flexdashboard Tabs with DT's fillContainer=T](https://xvrdm.shinyapps.io/tab-on-flex/#section-flexdashboard-tabs-with-dtfillcontainer)

````
Flexdashboard Tabs with DT::FillContainer
======================

Column {.tabset .tabset-fade}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### iris 

```{r}
DT::datatable(
    iris,
    fillContainer = T,
    rownames = F)
```

### mtcars 

```{r}
DT::datatable(
    mtcars,
    fillContainer = T,
    rownames = F)
```
````

I am now trying to use tabs generated dynamically by shiny with `tabsetPanel` instead of flexdashboard tabs. I tried both with and without `fillContainer=T`. But the datatables don't fill the container exactly and are either too long in height or very short (less than 2 rows). In both cases the pagination options show below the last row and not at the bottom of the container.

[Shinyapps.io : Shiny Tabs with DT's fillContainer=T](https://xvrdm.shinyapps.io/tab-on-flex/#section-shiny-tabs-with-dtfillcontainer)

````
Shiny Tabs with DT::fillContainer 
======================

Column {.tabset .tabset-fade}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Tabs container with fillContainer

```{r}
library(shiny)
tabsetPanel(
  tabPanel("iris",
    DT::datatable(
      iris,
      fillContainer = T,
      rownames = F)),
  tabPanel("mtcars",
    DT::datatable(
      mtcars,
      fillContainer = T,
      rownames = F))  
)
```
````

[Shinyapps.io : Shiny Tabs without DT's fillContainer=T](https://xvrdm.shinyapps.io/tab-on-flex/#section-shiny-tabs-without-dtfillcontainer)

````
Shiny Tabs without DT::fillContainer 
======================

Column {.tabset .tabset-fade}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Tabs container without fillContainer

```{r}
library(shiny)
tabsetPanel(
  tabPanel("iris",
    DT::datatable(
      iris,
      fillContainer = F,
      rownames = F)),
  tabPanel("mtcars",
    DT::datatable(
      mtcars,
      fillContainer = F,
      rownames = F))  
)
```
````

Any idea on how to get proper filling of containers?
Thanks a lot

Comment: my bad, i thought it is about the width (the alignment on the right) ;)

Comment: I am also facing these issues, any fix so far?

Answer (score 0):

Set `fillContainer = FALSE`

Add `style = "height:550px; overflow-y: scroll;"` as an argument to tabPanel.

I used this successfully in shinydashboard where tabPanels are part of the tabBox argument.